# Recording files get 0 kb in kurento media server latest development version

Tags: node.js, recording, kurento

In kurento mediaserver recording some times recordings file get 0 kb. in local machine it is not happening frequently but in server it happence frequently. is this due to slow internet connection ? i always call stop record when a client disconnect. is there any valid solution . using kurento 6.4 development version

Comment: Can you specify under which circumstances the video recorded gets 0KB? I'd guess that's because no media is arriving at the media server, because no webrtc connection could be established during the ICE negotiation process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kurento recording not recording any data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160648/kurento-recording-not-recording-any-data)

Comment: No duplicate, because issue on NodeJS. Any news about that? I´m facing the same problem, haven´t managed to get it working a single time. On the other hand the Browser to Kurento sample without application layer is working fine. I´m on windows with Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM with kurento installed

Comment: Did you guys ever get this working?